# Maven dependency resolution in a project with modules

Tags: installation, maven

my maven project is stuctured as:

```
project
  moduleA
  moduleB
  moduleC
```

The moduleB and moduleC are dependend on moduleA. if I execute the 'mvn install' command maven installs moduleA and moduleB in my local repository after that maven tries to install the modeleC but without success, first it tries to find the artifact moduleA in all known maven remote repositories and after that, I'm getting a message that the moduleA artefact is missing. Its so weard because sometimes it works fine and sometimes not. Because of this issue I wasted a lot of time.

The artifact moduleA and moduleB are in my local repository.

I'm using maven 2.2.1 on a 64Bit machine under windows 7 pro.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use mvn install, that command will put the artifact in your local repository.  Usually in your home directory under .m2/repository unless you have specified differently. If moduleC is trying build (with mvn install) and depends on moduleA, moduleA should be pulling from your local repository when moduleC.  If moduleC is looking remotely for moduleA then moduleA never got installed into your local repository.

Check the pom file for moduleC.  Make sure the dependency information in moduleC's pom.xml for moduleA matches the groupId, artifactId, and version specified in moduleA's pom.xml.  If that matches, make sure moduleA is really producing an artifact.  It should be in the target directory under moduleA.  If moduleA is not a jar make sure you have the type attribute listed in the pom.xml for moduleA and that moduleC's pom.xml has that type listed for the dependency.

If the above doesn't lead to a consistent resolution, you're may want to edit your question adding some of the pom.xml details.